# In hash, what does values in a square brackets means? language is Perl

Tags: perl, hash

Source code:

```
$Bo2l = 'TGYTCM';

%amb = ( Y => "[CT]", M => "[TG]", D => "[AGT]", N => "[AGCT]");

foreach $key_amb(keys%amb){ 
    $Bo2l =~ s/$key_amb/$amb{$key_amb}/g;   
}
$sequence = 'AAAAAATGATTGCTCATTTGCTCTGCTCGCAAAAAAAAATGATTATTTTTT';

for($i=0; $i<length($sequence)-5; $i++){
    $cutseq = substr($sequence, $i, 6);
    if($cutseq =~ m/$Bo2l/){
        $pos = $i+1;
        print "Bo2l\t$pos\t$cutseq\n";
    }
}
```

I can understand the `$sequence`, but I can't understand what those square brackets do.

Comment: `"[CT]"` => plain string

Comment: Since the string values in the hash `%Bo2l` are interpreted as regular expressions in your code, they are regular expression syntax. It denotes a character class match operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square brackets are "character class" delimiters.  so `"[CT]"` means "match either a `C` or a `T`".

Comment: I feel like this answer could use some more context: The question in the title is *"In hash, what does values in a square brackets means?"*, to which the answer is "nothing special, it's just a string", but in the context of the code shown, the hash values are interpreted as regular expressions, to which this answer applies.

Comment: @haukex I agree in general with your comment,  but I answered what I took to be the spirit of the question, which perhaps should have been phrased  as 'In this code snippet, what does... etc'